# How does ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries().Select().OfType() work?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to understand the mechanism that makes this code that I lifted from another SO question work:

```
        List<ResourceType> ResourceTypes2 =
            this.ObjectStateManager
                .GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added)
                .Select(entry => entry.Entity)
                .OfType<ResourceType>().ToList();
```

Is the above an object query or an EF query?

The reason I'm asking is I'm using it with a table that stores > 100K rows, and I want to make sure it doesn't have to do some kind of row enumeration.

As side question I have is what are thoughts on using the above mechanism to implement an Upsert facility that works by letting client code simply delete and then add to a context, but upon save, compares deleted with added  to achieve updates where the row already exists?  It would be a "mode" that the context is put into so as to not have side effected semantics.

Comment: It is LINQ to Objects on the ObjectContext/StateManager data structures in memory (because it isn't an `IQueryable` as explained in @rich.okelly's answer) and won't issue any database queries. To your "Upsert" idea: I don't see what's the benefit of that procedure and would say: Don't protect clients from understanding how to work correctly with EF. If they need to update, they should use the mechanisms for that (load from DB/Attach/ApplyCurrentValues/Change tracking, etc) and not call clumsy DeleteObject/AddObject pairs.

Comment: maybe i'm missing something - i seem to be the only one I know that hates typing the code over and over to see if an object exists already and adding it if so, and updating it wise.... it is tedious boilerplate, right?

Answer (score 1):

It very much depends on the return type of this.ObjectStateManager
                .GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added)

If it returns an IEnumerable any subsequent operations will be using the LinqToObjects implementations, whereas if it returns an IQueryable you'll be using the EF implementations.

Personally, I wouldn't like the idea of the custom Upsert mechanism as it would steepen the learning curve for anyone wishing to develop your code in the future, but this is just my opinion. For a discussion on the pros and cons of the mechanism I'd suggest a seperate question or a post on the discussions section.

Hope this helps.